# How can I scrape a table from the website in the question

Tags: html, r, web, rvest

I am trying to copy a table from a webpage, there are going to be many as I am trying to get the versions of the data for each dataset, I am trying to get at least one table but failing. Scraping is not my thing, maybe it is obvious how to get it but not to me.

Here is my code:

```r
url <- "https://data.cms.gov/provider-characteristics/medicare-provider-supplier-enrollment/medicare-fee-for-service-public-provider-enrollment/api-docs"

html <- rvest::read_html(url)
> html |> rvest::html_node(".table")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

And

```r
> html |>
 rvest::html_node(xpath = "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody")
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

And

```r
html |>
  rvest::html_node("tbody")
```

The output showed that javascript needed to be enabled. The first answer works for the current dataset and the second answer I posted works to get most of the distributions where accessURL and title are present in the output.

Comment: What does the output of `html` show? Does it show, "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app"? If so, then you might consider using `RSelenium`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this approach is not going to work. The tables in the page you're looking at are generated via JavaScript. The `rvest::read_html(url)` call will retrieve the *static* content on that page but will not execute any (dynamic) JavaScript.

But there is an API behind the site, so you can get the data directly from that. For example:

```r
library(httr)

params = list(
  `path` = "/provider-characteristics/medicare-provider-supplier-enrollment/medicare-fee-for-service-public-provider-enrollment"
)

res <- httr::GET(url = "https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/slug", query = params)

cat(content(res, as="text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Alternatively you can use something like `{RSelenium}` to evaluate the JavaScript and then scrape the fully rendered page.

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to get most of what I want by doing the following:

```r
url <- "https://data.cms.gov/data.json"

data_sets <- httr2::request(url) |>
  httr2::req_perform() |>
  httr2::resp_body_json(check_type = FALSE, simplifyVector = TRUE)

data_tbl <- data_sets$dataset |>
  dplyr::tibble() |>
  dplyr::select(title, modified, keyword, description, contactPoint, identifier) |>
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(keyword, contactPoint)) |>
  dplyr::select(-`@type`) |>
  dplyr::mutate(hasEmail = stringr::str_remove(hasEmail, "mailto:"))

data_distribtution <- function(.data){
  df <- .data
  
  dplyr::tibble(data = df[["dataset"]][["distribution"]]) |>
    dplyr::mutate(cnm = purrr::map(data, \(x) names(x))) |>
    dplyr::mutate(title_in_col = purrr::map(cnm, \(x) "title" %in% x) |> unlist()) |>
    dplyr::mutate(accessURL_in_col = purrr::map(cnm, \(x) "accessURL" %in% x) |> unlist()) |>
    dplyr::filter(title_in_col == TRUE & accessURL_in_col == TRUE) |>
    dplyr::select(data) |>
    dplyr::mutate(data = purrr::map(
      data, \(x) x |>
        dplyr::select(title, modified, temporal, accessURL, 
                      downloadURL, mediaType) |>
        dplyr::mutate(data_link = dplyr::coalesce(accessURL, downloadURL)) |>
        dplyr::mutate(mediaType = ifelse(is.na(mediaType), "api", mediaType)) |>
        dplyr::mutate(modified = as.Date(modified)) |>
        dplyr::select(-accessURL, -downloadURL) |>
        dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(modified), mediaType)
    )) |>
    tidyr::unnest(cols = c(data))
}
```

Sample Output

```r
> data_distribtution(.data = data_sets) |>
+   head(1) |>
+   dplyr::glimpse()
Rows: 1
Columns: 5
$ title     <chr> "Accountable Care Organization Participants : 2024-01-24"
$ modified  <date> 2024-01-29
$ temporal  <chr> "2024-01-01/2024-12-31"
$ mediaType <chr> "api"
$ data_link <chr> "https://data.cms.gov/data-api/v1/dataset/9767cb68-8ea9-4f0b-8179-9431abc89f1…
```